# Why is CodeIgniter exhausing allowed memory size?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, windows-8.1, iis-8

I am getting a memory exhausted error where I should not be taking up any memory!

The application is on Windows 8 Server / IIS i / PHP 5.5/ CodeIgniter / MS SQL Server

The error is as follows:

> [23-May-2014 10:56:57 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed
>   memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1992
>   bytes) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\models\DW_import.php
>   on line 112
>
> [23-May-2014 11:07:34 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error: 
>   Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   2438 bytes) in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\models\DW_import.php on line 113

The script looks for several different CSV files in a directory to import into a database. Keep in mind the import files are huge, some up to 4 Gigs of data. So far as I can see, there are not variables that continually aggregating data that could lead to this issue. The script (model) being run (there is no view for this controller, only model) is as follows:

DW_import.php

```
<?php

class dw_import extends CI_Model {

    public function import(){

        global $file,$errLogFile,$logFile,$tableName, $fieldList, $file, $count, $line, $query;

        $this->load->database(); // init db connection

        // map file types to database tables
        $fileToDBArr = array(
            'Customers' => 'customer',
            'Customers_Historical' => 'customer_historical',
            'Orders' => 'order',
            'Customer_AR_Aggs' => 'customer_ar_aging_agg'
        );

        // extend timeout of this script
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);

        // error handler to log errors and continue processing
        function myErrorHandler($errno,$errstr,$errfile,$errline){

            global $file,$errLogFile,$logFile,$tableName, $fieldList, $file, $count, $line, $query;
            // error - store in DB
            //echo "<br>[$errno $errstr $errfile $errline $tableName $file $count] $errLogFile<br>";
            $err = "#$errno $errstr $errfile on line $errline :: Table $tableName File $file Row# $count Headers: $fieldList Data: $line";
            echo $err;
            file_put_contents($errLogFile,$err,FILE_APPEND);
        };

        set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

        // set temp error log file
        $errLogFile = "C:/Data_Updates/logs/general." . date('YmdHis') . ".errLog";

        // loop thru file types
        foreach($fileToDBArr as $fileType=>$table){
            // get the files for this import type
            $fileArr = glob('C:/Data_Updates/'.$fileType.'.*');
            sort($fileArr,SORT_STRING); // sort so earlier files (by date in file name) will process first

            // loop thru files found
            foreach($fileArr as $file){
                // set log file paths specific to this import file
                $errLogFile = str_replace('Data_Updates/','Data_Updates/logs/',$file) . "." . date('YmdHis') . ".errLog";
                $logFile = str_replace('Data_Updates/','Data_Updates/logs/',$file) . "." . date('YmdHis') . ".log";

                file_put_contents($logFile,"---BEGIN---",FILE_APPEND); // log

                // lets get the file type and translate it into a table name
                preg_match('/C:\/Data_Updates\/([^\.]+)/',$file,$matches);
                $fileType = $matches[1];
                $tableName = $fileToDBArr[$fileType];


                // lets get the first row as a field list
                $fp = fopen($file,'r');
                //$fieldList = str_replace('"','',fgets($fp));

                // counters to track status
                $count = 0;
                $startPoint = 0;

                // see if continuation, set startPoint to last row imported from file
                $query = "SELECT max(import_line) as maxline FROM $tableName WHERE import_file = '" . addslashes($file) . "'";
                $result = $this->db->query($query);

                foreach($result->result() as $row) $startPoint = $row->maxline+1; // set the startPoint if this is continuation

                file_put_contents($logFile,"\nstartPoint $startPoint",FILE_APPEND); // log      

                // loop thru file lines
                while (!feof($fp)) {
                    $line = fgets($fp);
                    // reformat those pesky dates from m/d/y to y-m-d
                    $line = preg_replace('/, ?(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/',',${3}-${1}-${2}',$line);

                    if(!$count){
                        // header row - set aside to use for column headers on insert statements
                        $fieldList = str_replace('"','',$line);
                        file_put_contents($logFile,"\nHeaders: $fieldList",FILE_APPEND); // log
                    } elseif($count >= $startPoint && trim($line)) {

                        // data row - insert into DB
                        $lineArr = str_getcsv($line); // turn this CSV line into an array
                        // build the insert query
                        $query = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($fieldList,import_date,import_file,import_line)
                        VALUES (";
                        foreach($lineArr as $k=>$v) $query .= ($v !== '') ? "'".addslashes(utf8_encode($v))."'," : " NULL,";
                        $query .= "now(),'" . addslashes($file). "',$count)
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
                        foreach(explode(',',$fieldList) as $k=>$v) $query .= "\n$v=" . (($lineArr[$k] !== '') ? "\"" . addslashes(utf8_encode($lineArr[$k])) . "\"" : "NULL") . ", ";
                        $query .= "import_date = now(),import_file='" . addslashes($file) . "',import_line = $count ";


                        if(!$this->db->query($query)) {
                            trigger_error('db error ' . $this->db->_error_number() . ' ' . $this->db->_error_message());
                            $status = 'error ';
                        } else {
                            $status = 'success ';   
                        };

                        file_put_contents($logFile,"row: $count status: $status data: $line",FILE_APPEND); // log'

                    } else {
                        // skipped - this row was already imported from this file
                        // removed log to speed up
                        file_put_contents($logFile,"row: $count status: SKIPPED data: $line",FILE_APPEND); // log
                    }; // if $count
                    $count++;
                }; // while $fp
                fclose($fp);

                // file complete - move file to archive
                rename($file,str_replace('Data_Updates/','Data_Updates/archive/',$file));
                file_put_contents($logFile,"-- END --",FILE_APPEND); // log
            }; // each $fileArr

        }; // each $globArr

    } // end import function
} // end class 

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

************ EDIT

---

Based on recommendations from several folks, I have added some changes. These changes only effect the "data row insert to DB" section of the loop logic. You can see the addition of logging to track the memory_get_peak_usage, addition of unset() and clearcachestat(). below the code is some of the log data:

```
                        file_put_contents($logFile,memory_get_peak_usage() . " line 1 \n\r",FILE_APPEND); 
                        // data row - insert into DB
                        if(isset($lineArr)) unset($lineArr); 
                        file_put_contents($logFile,memory_get_peak_usage() . " line 1.1 \n\r",FILE_APPEND);
                        $lineArr = str_getcsv($line); // turn this CSV line into an array
                        // build the insert query
                        file_put_contents($logFile,memory_get_peak_usage() . " line 2 lineArr size: " . strlen(implode(',',$lineArr)) . "\n\r",FILE_APPEND);
                        if(isset($query)) unset($query);  
                        file_put_contents($logFile,memory_get_peak_usage() . " line 2.1 lineArr size: " . strlen(implode(',',$lineArr)) . "\n\r",FILE_APPEND);
                        $query = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($fieldList,import_date,import_file,import_line)
                        VALUES (";
                        file_put_contents($logFile,memory_get_peak_usage() . " line 2.2 lineArr size: " . strlen(implode(',',$lineArr)) . "\n\r",FILE_APPEND);
                        foreach($lineArr as $k=>$v) $query .= ($v !== '') ? "'".addslashes(utf8_encode($v))."'," : " NULL,";
                        $query .= "now(),'" . addslashes($file). "',$count)
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
                        file_put_contents($logFile,memory_get_peak_usage() . " line 2.3 lineArr size: " . strlen(implode(',',$lineArr)) . "\n\r",FILE_APPEND);

                        foreach(explode(',',$fieldList) as $k=>$v) $query .= "\n$v=" . (($lineArr[$k] !== '') ? "\"" . addslashes(utf8_encode($lineArr[$k])) . "\"" : "NULL") . ", ";
                        file_put_contents($logFile,memory_get_peak_usage() . " line 2.4 lineArr size: " . strlen(implode(',',$lineArr)) . "\n\r",FILE_APPEND);
                        $query .= "import_date = now(),import_file='" . addslashes($file) . "',import_line = $count ";
                        file_put_contents($logFile,memory_get_peak_usage() . " line 3 query size: " . strlen($query) . "\n\r",FILE_APPEND);

                        if(!$this->db->query($query)) {
                            trigger_error('db error ' . $this->db->_error_number() . ' ' . $this->db->_error_message());
                            $status = 'error ';
                        } else {
                            $status = 'success ';   
                        };

                        clearstatcache();
```

Log data:(leftmost number is the result of the memory_get_peak_usage() call

```
2724960 line 1.1 
2724960 line 2 lineArr size: 194
2724960 line 2.1 lineArr size: 194
2724960 line 2.2 lineArr size: 194
2724960 line 2.3 lineArr size: 194
2727392 line 2.4 lineArr size: 194
2727392 line 3 query size: 2346

2727392 line 1 
2727392 line 1.1 
2727392 line 2 lineArr size: 194
2727392 line 2.1 lineArr size: 194
2727392 line 2.2 lineArr size: 194
2727392 line 2.3 lineArr size: 194
2729944 line 2.4 lineArr size: 194
2729944 line 3 query size: 2346

2729944 line 1 
2729944 line 1.1 
2729944 line 2 lineArr size: 194
2729944 line 2.1 lineArr size: 194
2729944 line 2.2 lineArr size: 194
2729944 line 2.3 lineArr size: 194
2732448 line 2.4 lineArr size: 194
2732448 line 3 query size: 2346

2732448 line 1.1 
2732448 line 2 lineArr size: 194
2732448 line 2.1 lineArr size: 194
2732448 line 2.2 lineArr size: 194
2732448 line 2.3 lineArr size: 194
2735088 line 2.4 lineArr size: 194
2735088 line 3 query size: 2346
```

NOTE that the memory is still growing between line 2.3 and 2.4 which is the following line of code:

```
foreach(explode(',',$fieldList) as $k=>$v) $query .= "\n$v=" . (($lineArr[$k] !== '') ? "\"" . addslashes(utf8_encode($lineArr[$k])) . "\"" : "NULL") . ", ";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could scatter `memory_get_peak_usage()` readings throughout the code to see where the usage jumps up.

Comment: thanks @halfer . I did and found 2 spots where the memory is increasing, but should not be: #1) $lineArr = str_getcsv($line); and #2) $query = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($fieldList,....". This is in a loop, but in both scenarios I would expect the variable to simply overwrite itself. Instead it looks like memory is continuing to aggregate each iteration. I checked the variables and they are indeed overwriting the previous values (so the contents are not getting larger with each iteration). Still stumped...

Comment: What database engine are you using - PDO? You might be able to throw away `$query` objects after using them. (If you can edit your update into your question, and delete your comment, that keeps the current state of the question in one place).

Comment: Also, try `unset`ting these variables after they are used in the loop.

Comment: Ahhh I did try unset after I identified the problem variables, it seems to work for #1, but not for #2.

Comment: See my earlier point (and question) about item 2.

Comment: @halfer: I am using mysql driver class built into CodeIgnitor. I added unset() to the 2 variables that are causing the problem as well as some additional logging. Unset has helped but still there is an issue. Check out my edits. PS: Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: Ah, I was going to suggest `mysql_free_result`, but the query does not appear to be the cause of the increase (though you could try it anyway).

Comment: Why is `$file` defined as a global (twice!) when it is used as an iteration variable in a `foreach` loop? That looks suspect. Try to reduce, and then eliminate, global vars where you can.

Comment: @hafler the $file (and the other set of variables) set to global twice was a resolution to another challenge - needing to access those variables in my custom error handler. I tried having global declared once (both inside and outside the error handler) and both did not allow me access to the variables inside of the error handler . Only having it in both place worked. Thinking it has something to do with the code being in one function and the error handler being a function within that function.

Comment: No no, it's set to global twice in the same list: `$file,$errLogFile,$logFile,$tableName, $fieldList, $file, $count, $line, $query;`. But yes, there will definitely be a better way of doing this: make them class properties, and then set the error handler to a class method.

Comment: Also, split up the `foreach` onto separate lines (you should always use braces anyway) and see what call is responsible for the increase.

Comment: @helfer got it on the global issue. As far as the memory issue: I expect the foreach to increase memory usage with each "$query .=". Isn't the concern why the "unset" function is not clearing the memory of each variable, or why when I set the variable "$query = " it does not overwrite the memory being used by the same variable in the previous iteration of the loop?

Comment: It could be `explode`, `addslashes` or `utf8_encode` that causes the increase (i.e. not just variable assignments) so they need to be split up. I would fix the global issue first, since that might have a memory impact that then needs to be dealt with. It might be worth unsetting `$k` and `$v` too, maybe? Don't forget to add in your `unset`s in the code here so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
$this->load->database(); // init db connection, already in code
$this->db->save_queries = false; // ADD THIS LINE TO SOLVE ISSUE
```

This is a lovely undocumented setting in CodeIgniter. CI apparently saves queries by default, even a certain amount of data is saved relative to insert / update queries. With the massive amount of inserts run during this import process, this memory leak became very consequential. Setting CI to not save queries solved the problem.

What threw me off was that `memory_get_peak_usage()` was reporting the memory usage increasing *before* the insert query was run, not during it (PHP bug?).

As a final reality check, I removed all the other optimization recommendations (`unset`, `clearstatcache`, etc) and verified that they had no positive impact on the memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `set_time_limit(0)` to define the time limit of the proccess.. and between the loops you can clean the cache from mram using `clearstatcache();`

Comment: I added clearstatcache() but still getting the memory leak. Check edits above to see the changes and the log results.